# d3js: Multiple values have a date range (jan 1 - jan 20 = 300), I want totals for a period that can be shorter

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get a lot of visualisation options from one big tsv with data.
I'm using d3 to create a lot of cool stats.

The data is structured as follows:
    item,startdate,enddate,value

So, let's say we have this list of 3 similar items in dec/january:

```
gasoline,20-12-2009,10-01-2010,400
gasoline,01-01-2010,31-01-2010,1000
gasoline,21-01-2010,31-01-2010,900
```

As you can see, most are completely in january but the first item is partly in december of the previous year. So if I want the total for january 400+1000+900 wouldn't be correct.

I could parse the data and make separate entries per day, put this doesn't feel futureproof and I could get nasty rounding errors.

On load I do this:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.startdate = StatsLoader.format.parse(String(d.startdate));
    d.enddate = StatsLoader.format.parse(String(d.enddate));
    d.period = (d.enddate - d.startdate) / StatsLoader.periodSize; // 86400000, 1 day in ms
    d.value = +d.value;
});
```

So I have a nice object with a name, start and enddate, a value and I know the period in days.

Now I'd like to get the sum in a date range, but I don't know where to start.

My normal 'sum' function would look like this (assuming more than one item name)

```
var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.item; })
    .entries(data);

var piechartData = [];
nest.forEach(function(n) {
    piechartData.push({
    name: n.key,
    value: d3.sum(n.values, function(d) { return d.value; })
    })
})
```

I feel like I should be using quantize somehow? Or domains?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a date range given by a start and end date, the code to compute the (partial) sums would be something like this.

```
function getTotal(range, data) {
  var sum = 0;
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    if(d.startdate <= range.startdate && d.enddate >= range.enddate) {
      var duration = (Math.min(d.enddate, range.enddate) -
                     Math.max(d.startdate, range.startdate)) / StatsLoader.periodSize;
      sum += d.value / d.period * duration;
    }
  });
  return sum;
}
```

You can optimise this code of course. This works for arbitrary ranges.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good solution. Maybe I was looking at it too much like d3 should have had it figured out already ;)

On the way home I thought it might be possible to extend or alter the domain functions somehow. It feels like your suggested solution could be intensive with large datasets... Or no?

Comment: Certainly -- it's an n^2 algorithm. You can almost certainly improve on that by using better data structures etc.

Comment: So would you recommend pre-processing my data? Splitting my values in days/months and then using d3? lots of memory...